# I used another workspace for the admin controller and the controllers that are not inside the admin directory do not work properly, Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I began symfony not long ago and I was using it properly until I started to give users access based on their roles, I had to create an Admin directory inside the controller's one and use the namespace App\Controller\Admin for the ones inside it and App\Controller for those inside Controller.
[This is a controller that is directly inside Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnGwI.png)
[This one is inside the Admin Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VANLs.png)

The problem is that, when I return render in the controllers that are not inside the admin directory, instead of having the right page, I'm sent to the index one, but when the controller is inside the Admin directory, I'm sent to the right page. I cannot even logout it is as if Symfony does not know the paths no more, but not for the redirectToRoute() function, when it is used the page is found properly
[Instead of the user being logged out, he is just back to the index and still logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klBDC.png)

I tried to give a role for simple users, one that will allow them to go anywhere except admin, and it still did not worked. [Access to all the pages that are not admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0sTE.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)